# Best practice for CLI utility help file

Tags: c, getopt, helpfile

I've finished implementing a command-line utility that parses arguments via getopt_long.  To wrap things up, I need to implement a -h or --help switch that will print out the list of arguments as well as descriptions and default values.

Is there a GNU framework that I can utilize for this?  If not, I realize that there are several ways I can do this manually.  What's generally seen as the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
#include <getopt.h>
int getopt_long(int argc, char * const argv[],
           const char *optstring,
           const struct option *longopts, int *longindex);
```

See `man 3 getopt_long` on how to use it.

And on what to print in the output of your `--help option`, you can read

> **GNU Coding Standards**
>
> 4.7.2 ‘--help’

http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#g_t_002d_002dhelp

Answer (score 1):

[argp_parse()](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html) is the current gnu framework for argument parsing.  It replaces getopt() and getopt_long(), which should now be considered obsolete.

Comment: Does anyone know of an argp.h implementation for MSVC?